# Unsure why my CSS is not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the textboxes to float over the canvas in the appropriate spot.

If I use the id's to implement the css, it doesn't work.  But If I specify the html element in the CSS instead, it works. (though, then I cannot manipulate the unique textboxes) (Demonstrated by the canvas tag)

Little Help?

```
<style type="text/css">
canvas { position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
top:0px;
left:100px;
}

.wrapper{ height:100%;
width:100%;                 
}

.username { position:absolute;
top:200px;
left:150px;
visibility:hidden;
z-index:1;
}

.password { position:absolute;
top:300px;
left:150px;
visibility:hidden;
z-index:2;
}

</style>

</head>
    <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <canvas id = "gamescreen" height = "800" width = "800"></canvas>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /> 
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `.` selector works on classes. If you want to select elements using their id you need to use `#` infront of the id. Example:

CSS

> #example {
>         background: black;
>     }

HTML

> ```
> <div id="example></div>
> ```

Comment: **facepalm** Should've remembered that.

Comment: Haha we all have no problem, glad I could get my first reputation point :p

Answer (score 1):

What you've implemented are CSS **classes**. Declare your `div` with `class="wrapper"` etc to apply those styles. You should also probably specify a finer-grained class for those particular styles, such as `input.username`, `input.password` and `div.wrapper`. Or if you want it done just for the specific element and aren't planning to reuse those styles anywhere else, change the `.` prefix to a `#` to match the `id` of the element rather than its `class`.